# Unable to set content-type and browser opens file inline for a text file in Java

Tags: java, file, header, content-type, mime

I am surely doing this all wrong, so please tell me what should be the correct syntax for setting headers. I want to force (or tell) the browser to download this text file I am creating, not just open it inline.

I am just doing plain Java here, and I don't have `JSP` or `Servlet`, so I cannot use `response.setContentType()`

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("c:/vikkee/MyFile.csv");
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

pw.println("Content-Type: application/octet-stream;"); 
pw.println("Content-Disposition: attachment;");
pw.println("This is a text file");
pw.println("And this should not open inline in the browser");
```

Right now, the file opens inline and the browser shows this data as content, would like a way to define the headers in an alternate way so that it won't be considered as actual contents.

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; 
Content-Disposition: attachment;
```

This is a text file and this should not open inline in the browser.

Comment: It would perhaps be helpful if you posted some minimal compilable and runnable example so that others can easily reproduce your problem.

Comment: Updated formatting.